# Serving non-public binary files from a Rack application

Tags: ruby, rack

I am making a simple rack application that grant access to secured files after an authentication.
As the data in the files is sensitive, they are located in a non-public folder of the application.

For now, after checking the session data, I just open the file for read and send the content as the body of the response.
It feels ugly and must be very ressource consuming for larger files.

Example response:

```
[ "200", {"Content-Type"=> MIME::Types.type_for(file).first.to_s }, File.open( file ).read() ]
```

I looked into [Rack::Sendfile](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/Rack/Sendfile.html), but as far as I understand it, it is a middleware and cannot send files from inside the application itself.

What would the most efficient way to send non-public binary files from a Rack application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Rack response body must respond to `#each{|d|}`. So you could stream the response like this:

```
class FileStreamer
  def initialize(path)
    @file = File.open(path)
  end

  def each(&blk)
    @file.each(&blk)
  ensure
    @file.close
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
[ "200", {"Content-Type"=> MIME::Types.type_for(file).first.to_s }, FileStreamer.new(file) ]
```

Comment: Thanks you, would that require to add "use Rack::Chunked" in config.ru to work best?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, if you use a [Rack::Response object](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/Rack/Response.html) you can do something like this:

```
response = Rack::Response.new
file = open(path_to_binary_file, "rb")
# other stuff…
mime = Mime.mime_type(::File.extname(file.path), 'text/html')
response.headers.merge!( "Content-Type" => mime ) if mime
response.write file
response.finish
```